¿como hago que los correos que mando de visual studio no los tome como spam?
la razon, tengo un proyecto donde desde un formulario de visual studio debo de enviar el un asunto, mensaje y archivos pero al momento de enviarlo los correos a donde los envie me los toma como spam y sin mostrar los archivos que se enviaron.
        SmtpClient clienteSmtp = new SmtpClient("smtp-mail.outlook.com");//smtp
        clienteSmtp.Port = 587; //puerto del smtp
        clienteSmtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(CORREO_USUARIO.Text, CORREO_CONTRASEÑA.Text);//credenciales 
        clienteSmtp.EnableSsl = true; // Habilitar SSL
        MailMessage correo = new MailMessage();
        correo.From = new MailAddress(CORREO_USUARIO.Text);
        correo.To.Add(CORREO_DESTINATARIO.Text); // Agregar correo del destinatario
        correo.Subject = CORREO_ASUNTO.Text; // Agregar el asunto del correo
        correo.Body = mensaje.Text; // mensaje del correo

        try
        {
            // Enviar el correo
            clienteSmtp.Send(correo);
            MessageBox.Show("Correo enviado correctamente.", "Éxito", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            Guardar();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error al enviar el correo: " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        finally
        {
            // Liberar recursos
            correo.Dispose();
            clienteSmtp.Dispose();
        }

